# how to make a json on a json

Tags: json, discord.py

hi I have a question I want to create a bot that has luck wheel and the prizes is in a json file but the problem is that the bot will be in many servers.. so i wanted to know how to make like this :

```json
{
  "example_of_server_id":{
                           "legandary luck":["first leg prize","second leg prize", "third leg prize],
                           "epic luck":["first epic prize", "second epic prize", "third epic prize"],
                           "normal luck":["first normal prize", "second normal prize", "third normal prize],
                           "bad luck":["first bad prize", "second bad prize", "third bad prize"]
}
```

and the bot do this all times that he enter in servers  but without the "first normal prize" and all things like he will do like: a [] after the bad and normal and epic and leg luck thx ! :D

Comment: you just made it, didn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you use Python.

You can use the [json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) ([beginner friendly version](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)).

It will be something like this

```
import json

object_a = {"legandary luck": ["first leg prize", "second leg prize", "third leg prize"],
            "epic luck": ["first epic prize", "second epic prize", "third epic prize"],
            "normal luck": ["first normal prize", "second normal prize", "third normal prize"],
            "bad luck": ["first bad prize", "second bad prize", "third bad prize"]}
json_a = json.dumps(object_a)

object_b = {"server_id": json_a}
json_b = json.dumps(object_b)
print(json_b)
```

However, the better approach is to simply just put `object_a` into `object_b` directly so that you do not have to dumps them twice.

```
object_b = {"server_id": object_a}
json_b = json.dumps(object_b)
```

Comment: WORKED THXXXXX SO MUCH